# How can I change the height of a EditText and a Button?

Tags: android, height, android-edittext

I have this `EditText` and Button, and I have to reduce its height. I try with `android:height="10px"` but it doesn't work. Btw `android:width="180px"` works OK, then I don't know why I can't adjust the height.

Here is the code:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/Movile"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/MovileLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:width="180px"
    android:height="10px"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/inviteButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/invite"
        android:width="100px"
        android:height="5px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `android:textSize` to the size of the text you want it to be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make android EditText smaller than default in height?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361332/how-to-make-android-edittext-smaller-than-default-in-height)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of setting values to `android:height="10px"` use `android:layout_height="10px"`

```
 android:layout_width="180px"
 android:layout_height="10px"
```

Comment: Did you edited in both of your EditText and Button? which is your parent layout?

Answer (score 7):

use `android:minHeight="120dp"` attribute. 
if need to increase height dynamically add
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 6):

You need to get rid of the `"wrap_content"` properties and just have the fixed width and height as so:

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/Movile"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/MovileLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="180px"
    android:layout_height="10px"/>

<Button
        android:id="@+id/inviteButton"
        android:text="@string/invite"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="5px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't decrase size of TextEdit if the font is too big inside.

try  `android:textSize='6sp'`

Comment: did u try above line along with android:layout_height="wrap_content" ?