# Adjust EditText to font size

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I'm wondering how to adjust height of edit text to te font size. I mean editText is always same hight no matter if i change fontSize to 5sp or leave default. Of course i could use something like this:

```
<EditText
         android:id="@+id/msgInput"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="20dp"
         android:inputType="textMultiLine"
         android:textSize="14sp"
         android:hint="@string/hintMsgInput">
</EditText>
```

but i also want to stretch if there are more than 1 line. How can i do it?

[EDIT]:

Ok,i solved it in this way:

```
msgInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgInput);
        msgInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (msgInput.getLineCount() > 1)
                {
                    msgInput.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                }
                else
                {
                    int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                    msgInput.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, height));
                }
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {         
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {         
            }

        });
```

Comment: Ok, maybe example will help http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18780140/edittexts.png of course there is layout_height="wrap_content" everywhere. Question was why the "10sp editText" has the same height as default one

Answer (score 6):

Check this

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/editText1" 
    android:textSize="5sp"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="hello h r u hello  h r u hello  h r u hello  h r u hello  h r u "
></EditText>
```

Answer (score 3):

set  edit text height as wrap_content

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: What i descriped it was when i use wrap_content so it's not the solution to me

Answer (score 2):

You are providing 20 dp constraint to the height of EditText.
It you want the textView to adjust the height in regard of Text size use

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Also by default single line is false. Which ensures multiple line true.

Comment: 20dp was only example, look at comment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make EditText height more than one line you can put in your EditText:

android:layout_height="fill_parent" and set android:layout_weight="1" to get more space for              adding more views in activity

Comment: But i want to stretch only if characters fill single line. By default i want to have 1 line

Comment: see this link it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361332/how-to-make-android-edittext-smaller-than-default-in-height

Answer (score 0):

you can use a scrollView, and add your editText in a ScrollView, and use this :

```
android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add @style page name

```
<style name="value_big" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
  <item name="android:textSize">35sp</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
  <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
  <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
  <item name="android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack">true</item>
</style>
```

call that inside your edit text

```
                  <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/msgtext"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    style="@style/value_big"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:layout_height="150dip"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:padding="5dip"> 
                  </EditText>
```

Answer (score -1):

set  android:focusable="false" in the editText