# How to change font size of title in EditTextPreference in Android?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I want to reduce a font size of a title in `EditTextPreference`.
Do anybody know how to do  it ?

Comment: Check this one. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361332/how-to-make-android-edittext-smaller-.than-default-in-height

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<EditText 
    android:text="EditText" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="20dp" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18787499/increasing-checkboxpreference-title-and-summary-text-size-and-glowing-of-an-pref)

Prefrence Screen:

```
<PreferenceCategory
android:key="prefcategory1"
android:title="GENERAL SETTINGS..." >

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:key="checkBoxdelete"
    android:layout="@layout/mylayout"     <!--linking it to mylayout.xml -->
    android:summary="Deletes old messages as limits are reached"
    android:title="Delete old messages" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

and **mylayout.xml**

```
<TextView android:id="@+android:id/title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="30px"
android:textStyle="bold"/>  

<TextView android:id="@+android:id/summary"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:paddingLeft="8dp"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="20px"
android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

By using this text you can increase or decrease the font size